# Using custom attributes in ExtJS Component

Tags: javascript, custom-attributes, extend, extjs

My application has been growing for the last year or so and I have finally started to split out common components by extending existing ones. I've found this to be really helpful - increasing speed of development and maintenance. My problem is that I haven't grasped the concept of using custom parameters on my components and was hoping that someone could offer some assistance in the following example. Specifically I don't seem to be able to access the custom parameter (myCustomParam) inside the proxy declared in the initComponent function:

```
MyEmployeeGrid = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
 myCustomParam: "CompanyX",
 initComponent:function() {
    //Store Reader
    var myReader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        root : 'objectsToConvertToRecords',
        idProperty: 'id',
        fields : [
            {name: 'id'},
            {name: 'employee', allowBlank:false},
            {name: 'department', allowBlank:false}
        ]
    });

    //Store Proxy
    var dwrProxy = new Ext.ux.data.DwrProxy({
            apiActionToHandlerMap : {
            read : {
                dwrFunction : EmployeeService.readCompanyEmployees,
                getDwrArgsFunction: function(request, recordDataArray, oldRecordDataArray) {
                    return [myCustomParam];
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //Setup Params for the grid
    Ext.apply(this, {
        store: new Ext.data.Store({
             proxy: dwrProxy,
            reader: myReader,
            autoLoad : true,
            autoSave: true
        }),
        columns: [{header: "Employee", dataIndex: 'employee'},
                    {header: "Department", dataIndex: 'department'}]
    });

    MyEmployeeGrid.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
} // eo function initComponent

,onRender:function() {
    MyEmployeeGrid.superclass.onRender.apply(this, arguments);
} // eo function onRender

});

Ext.reg('myemployeegrid', MyEmployeeGrid);
```

Answer (score 1):

`myCustomParam` is a property of the object in question. It is never declared as a variable in its own right. You can see this by running the code through [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/).

You want `this.myCustomParam`.

If you're trying to pass in parameters, however, you might want to try this way instead:

```
MyGrid = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
  constructor: function(cfg) {
    cfg = cfg || {};

    // ... do stuff ...

    MyGrid.superclass.constructor.call(this, cfg);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you mind clarifying how to instanciate MyGrid using the constructor. Is it simply `new MyGrid({ customParam: "value" });`? How about with xtype?

Comment: I've updated it so that that method above will work. Every property in the `cfg` item will be a property on the new grid. If you register `MyGrid` you would be able to construct one using `xtype`. (i.e. `Ext.reg(MyGrid, 'my-grid');`)

Comment: +1 for constructor suggestion. I believe constructor function is Ext 3.x+ preferred way of creating your own component. The Ext code uses it.

Comment: There is no need to override the constructor unless you plan on putting some code in it.  Adding configs directly on the class is just fine, and is preferred for things that truly are configs (and should be able to be set from calling code).  As an aside, the line `cfg = cfg || {}` is only required if you plan on adding something to `cfg`. As written in this code that line is pointless.

Comment: I didn't copy his code from `initComponent` because I thought it was clear to do that. I'll add a "do stuff" comment to make that clearer. Likewise to use `cfg` after guarding against it being undefined. I just got the impression that he was trying to figure how to get variables into `initComponent` call.

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong feeling this is to do with scope around the point at which getDwrArgsFunction is called. It possibly doesn't know what myCustomParam is (despite the fact this should possibly be this.myCustomParam, and that you'd want to set this after you'd applied any config) because it's not declared in the DwrProxy object and has no reference back to its owning MyEmployeeGrid object.

I'd debug/attempt to fix in the following way:

1. Rename myCustomParam to
   this.myCustomParam and test
2. Set scope and test
3. Create getDwrArgsFunction using
   createDelegate
   (http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Function.html#method-Ext.util.Functions-createDelegate)
   and test

DISCLAIMER: Some of those will be no good depending on your DwrProxy etc (which we can't see the code for)

Answer (score 0):

The proxy cannot access the variable because it is not defined in the scope of the proxy itself. I have been struggling with things like this in the past, I thought that components would act like closures and keep track of the variable, but they dont.

You can solve your problem by handing the scope of the grid to the handler function explicitly by making it a delegate, what you do have to change for that is making the variable you would like to access an instance variable instead of just a local variable.

Changes:

```
MyEmployeeGrid = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
    myCustomParam: "defaultValue",
    initComponent:function() {
    ...
    //Store Proxy
    var dwrProxy = new Ext.ux.data.DwrProxy({
            apiActionToHandlerMap : {
            read : {
                dwrFunction : EmployeeService.readCompanyEmployees,
                getDwrArgsFunction: function(request, recordDataArray, oldRecordDataArray) {
                    return [this.myCustomParam];
                }.createDelegate(this)
            }
        }
    });

var myGridInstance = new MyEmployeeGrid({ myCustomParam: 'ValueForThisInstance' });
```

Hope this helps you, good luck

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your post. Does this mean that I wouldn't be able to modify myCustomParam when creating the grid - I need to create an instance of MyEmployeeGrid for each company, therefore modifying myCustomParam when declaring the grid

Comment: Hi James, I changed the code a bit because it was wrong, the variable declaration did not need 'this' before it. By using the above you can set a default value to the variable and override it with a custom one during initialization of you instance. Hope it helps, let me know